# MYSQL - group by nickname but show all different versions?

Tags: mysql

Hi guy wonder if this is possible,

currently i have a table :

```
"(consensus  CHAR(40) NOT NULL," 
+ "identityb32  CHAR(40) NOT NULL,"
+ "pubdate  CHAR(40) NOT NULL,"
+ "dirport  CHAR(6) NOT NULL,"
+ "ip  CHAR(40) NOT NULL,"
+ "orport  CHAR(40) NOT NULL,"
+ "fingerprint  CHAR(40) NOT NULL,"
+ "nick  CHAR(40) NOT NULL,"
+ "version  CHAR(40) NOT NULL,"
+ "flags  VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,"
+ "identity  VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,"
+ "digest  CHAR(40) NOT NULL,"
+ "pubtime  CHAR(40) NOT NULL)"
)
```

i have a lot of data inserted into this database most of it duplicate, however what i want to do is to search the table, and only output the results where a nickname has more than one fingerprint

currently i am using the code :

```
SELECT nick, fingerprint, identity, ip, consensus FROM agorahooawayyfoe group by fingerprint;
```

to do this but this shows me all nicknames group by identiy, all 2,000 of them what i want is to narrow this down to only show me results where a nickname has more than 1 identity and to group i by these

is this possible in a mysql command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the nicknames that have more than one fingerprint, then use aggregation and having:

```
select nick
from agorahooawayyfoe
group by nick
having count(distinct fingerprint) > 1;
```

If you want the details, then join this back to the table:

```
select a.*
from agorahooawayyfoe a join
     (select nick
      from agorahooawayyfoe
      group by nick
      having count(distinct fingerprint) > 1
     ) n
     on a.nick = n.nick;
```

Comment: distinct agorahooawayyfoe  will be an error for unknown column i guess @Gordon Linoff?

Comment: @A.B . . . Yes, that is supposed to be a column name, not a table name.

Comment: i was literally thinking that i lack some knowledge, as it was by your side

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a `having by` to explicitly say that the identity must be bigger than 1. See this link: [W3Schools - SQL HAVING Clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)